# Insert +, - , < , > into HTML page as Strings/Characters

Tags: html

How can I insert +, - , < , > characters into HTML page.

I want to make them appear as the caption of buttons.

```
    <button id="button2" type="button">+</button>
    <button id="button3" type="button">-</button>
    <button id="button4" type="button"><</button>
    <button id="button5" type="button">></button>
```

above will not work. 
How can I do that?

Comment: Use the proper HTML entities, e.g. `&lt;` and `&gt;` for `<` and `>`.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ucUJIPa/1/

Comment: This question isn't precise enough. Did you have a problem with + and - (and < should probably work in many browsers) ?

Comment: +, - are ok, But it will make the button UI unclear(Like compressed).

Comment: Does `<button>` need `type="button"`?

Comment: @popnoodles `<button>` type defaults to "submit". So it might be necessary here, depending on the rest of the code.

Answer (score 4):

You can use HTML numbers and codes:

```
<button id="button2" type="button">&#43;</button>
<button id="button3" type="button">&#45;</button>
<button id="button4" type="button">&lt;</button>
<button id="button5" type="button">&gt;</button>
```

Here is a complete table: http://www.ascii-code.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
> = &gt;
< = &lt;
- = &minus;
```

google it for + sign :)